# Congruence of Quadratic Residues

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm have difficulty solving a problem in my textbook. I'm hoping someone out there can help me out, so that I can understand this. The problem is listed below

> Given that $p$ is an odd prime. Prove that the $\frac{p-1}{2}$ quadratic residues mod p are congruent to the following:
>
> $$1^2, 2^2, 3^2, \space \ldots, \space (\frac{p-1}{2})^2$$

Any ideas on how to solve this would be great.

Comment: What are your own thoughts? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Not really sure how to approach it, do you have any ideas of were to start?

Comment: Well, do you see why it will be enough to show that those numbers are distinct?

Comment: I do not know why that'd be enough, why?

Comment: Well, can you show that those numbers are in fact quadratic residues?

Comment: What numbers? The $\frac{p-1}{2}$ residues or the values $1^2, 2^2, 3^2, \space \ldots, \space (\frac{p-1}{2})^2$ ?

Comment: The $1^2,...$ (since these are the ones you have been asked to show are the residues).

Comment: Since the residues are the values of $a$ that satisfy $x^2 \equiv a \space mod \space p$, does this mean that $1^2, 2^2, 3^2, \space \ldots, \space (\frac{p-1}{2})^2$ are exactly those terms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** These are obviously quadratic residues, and there are $\frac{p-1}{2}$ numbers in the list $1^2, 2^2, \dots, \left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)^2$.

You will be finished if you can show they are all **distinct** modulo $p$.

Suppose to the contrary that $a^2\equiv b^2\pmod{p}$, where $a$ and $b$ are distinct numbers in the interval from $1$ to $\frac{p-1}{2}$, with say $b\gt a$.

Then $p$ divides $(b-a)(b+a)$. Argue now that this is impossible, since $b-a$ and $b+a$ are too small.